# I want my internet connection to disconnect automatically after completing 90 MB bandwidth, but HOW?

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I am using a modem (ZTE USB Modem FFF1) to connect to internet and I want it to disconnect automatically after completing 90 MB bandwidth (Downloaded data + Uploaded Data). Can anyone suggest how can I do this. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using a desktop computer running on Windows 8 Consumer Preview. There's no router. I just want to limit the bandwidth of my internet connection, considering sent data + received data.

Comment: @MarcksThomas By the way, I have rephrased the same question here http://superuser.com/questions/431357/how-to-make-a-dial-up-connection-disconnect-automatically-after-donwloading-up