# How to make a dial up connection disconnect automatically after downloading + uploading 90 MB data in Windows?

Tags: internet, windows-8-preview

I am using a modem (ZTE USB Modem FFF1) to connect to internet and I want it to disconnect automatically after completing 90 MB (Downloaded data + Uploaded Data). Can anyone suggest how can I do this. I am using a desktop computer running on Windows 8 Consumer Preview. There's no router. I am using a dial up connection to connect. I just want to limit the data usage of my internet connection, considering sent data + received data.

Comment: I see no one has to limit their DATA consumption while surfing the internet, but I want to do so.

Comment: Is the 90mb the expected file(s) size you want to regularly transfrer? Like log in, transfer x files and logout. Or do you want to monitor data usage and limit it to 90mb per session? Log in, watch data flow, when 90mb transferred, disconnect.

Comment: @jdh Yes, exactly, I want to monitor data usage and limit it to 90mb per session. Log in, watch data flow, when 90 MB transferred, disconnect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a *bandwidth monitor* tool or utility. There are a few out there. However, based off a simple search, it seems one of the better (and free) ones is [Softperfect's NetWorx](http://bit.ly/NnHbiR). One of the its feature is, it's able to end a dial-up connection when a cap is reach.